# Converting TIFF (DIMAP) to .xyz file format with GDAL

Tags: gdal, metadata, geotiff-tiff, gdal-translate

We are attempting to convert a .tif file into .xyz file.

We have been using gdal_translate on a linux box and this is the line we've used:

```
gdal_translate -strict -of XYZ ABC.tif ABC.xyz -mo ABC.dim
```

The file has three bands: NIR, red and green respectively and we are trying to extract these values.

The dim file is just the meta data details describing the .tiff file.

I currently get a segmentation fault when I run this line, can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: I suppose ASCII Gridded XYZ can store a single band. Try to add -b 1 for the first band, -b 2 for the second. You gave a meta tag after the input and output layer, you should move it before the input and output file. Where did you find this meta option? Has it any sense?

Comment: @Zoltan Thanks for the response, tried the extra inputs but to no avail. We added the meta tag in the hope that it might specify the band types as opposed to say, RGB. I should add that when we replace the ABC.tif with the ABC.dim file and remove both the -strict and -mo arguments, it produces an .xyz file, however the NIR and red values are far outside of the allowable ranges (700-2500 and 0-250 ?) with values like: 601656 and 3901018 (NIR,red resp.).

Comment: I've tested gdal_translate (GDAL 1.11.3) with an RGB image and it worked. Did you try gdalinfo on your tif?